# xrandr --rotate inverted is making a kind of mirror effect

Tags: xorg, xrandr, displaylink

I use a script to setup all my screen when I plug my laptop on my dock

```bash
xrandr --output eDP1 --off
xrandr --output DVI-I-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate inverted
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --primary
xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0
```

But the rotated screen is not really rotated... Some stuff are rotated, some not.

What is not rotated :

- Mouse cursor
- Wallpaper
- Any window display

What is rotated :

- Windows button (I mean actions, so to interact with a window you have to click where the button is supposed to be and not where it's displayed)
- The side of the screen where mouse come in and out

I tried it on gnome and pantheon desktop, and screen are plugged on displayLink (dell d-6000) dock.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What can i do to have a full and normal rotation ?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish... are you saying that you would like the mouse cursor to also be horizontally reversed?

Comment: I would like to have my screen upside down. Currently it display "normally" but you can interact with windows like if it was flipped.Sorry for not being clear but that bug is so strange, so it's hard to explain. I don't know if it's a bug or the result of a bad configuration

Comment: stop thinking about the "bug" and just say what you would like to happen to the screen ... are you saying that you would like the display to be rotated 180 degrees? (pick up the LCD and hold it upside down)

Comment: yes I want my screen to be rotated 180 degrees. It's already physically upside down, the problem is that the graphic rotation is not working on the computer...